# Combining UNION and LIMIT operations in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, union, limit

I have a **Jobs** and a **Companies** table, and I want to extract 20 jobs that meet the following criteria:

1. Jobs only from two (2) named companies
2. There can at most be 10 jobs per company

I have tried the following `SELECT` with `UNION DISTINCT`, but the problem is that the `LIMIT 0,10` applies to the whole result set. I want it to apply to each of the companies.

If there aren't 10 jobs per company, then the query should return all the jobs it finds.

```
SELECT c.name, j.title, j.`desc`, j.link 
  FROM jobs_job j
INNER JOIN companies_company c ON j.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name IN ('Company1')
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT c.name, j.title, j.`desc`, j.link 
  FROM jobs_job j
INNER JOIN companies_company c ON j.company_id = c.id
WHERE c.name IN ('Company2')
ORDER by name, title
LIMIT 0,10
```

I am new to MySQL, so realise there may be a smarter way to do this instead of with UNION, so any suggestions for improvements are definitely welcome.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html),

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an
>   individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose
>   the SELECT:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: I was going by the MySQL documentation that said the ORDER BY came after the UNION.....and forgot about the parentheses!

Thanks

Comment: @Mauro, che ne dici di accettare la risposta, se ti risolve il problema, eh?!-)  Usa il segno di "checkmark" sotto il numero di upvotes (attualmente tre...)...

Comment: This works in MySql, but it doesn't look like SQLite supports this in case anyone runs into this question on google

Comment: It will return max 20 records. And only if those are unique rows. U have to use UNION ALL on non-unique rows.

Comment: Prefect, just what I needed to get the fields I needed with limits on my two queries

Comment: If you know that the results are unique or you simply don't care if there are duplicates you should use `UNION ALL`. `UNION` removes duplicate rows. With `UNION` duplicates are removed which has - depending on the number of rows - a performance impact.

Answer (score 6):

Improving on Alex's answer and based on Joe's observation, the following should work in SQLite:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: answer needed a slight modification for me on SQLite. ```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: @PjToopmuch Yep. I'm going to try to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In Teradata we can't use union with top queries as it, if you do you get an error,  which needs to be tweaked as shown below. Adding solution for Teradata users.**

[image: Union and Top can written together as given below in Teradata]

Comment: we can use either "*" or  instead of "*" you can use , "user_defined_name1.*". Both approach works