# Can I Count How Many Results Come From Each MySQL Select / Union

Tags: php, mysql, count, limit, union

I have a query that follows this format:

```
(SELECT t.column1, t.column2
FROM table t 
WHERE t.status = 1 
LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT t.column1, t.column2 
FROM table t
WHERE t.status = 2 
LIMIT 10)
```

The end result is that I need to have 20 rows. If the first `SELECT` statement can only find 9 rows with `t.status = 1`, then I would like the second `SELECT` statement to use `LIMIT 11` instead of `LIMIT 10`

I am using PHP to write and run the query, but I am looking for something that will execute within MySQL so I can run it all as one query.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining UNION and LIMIT operations in MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query)

Comment: This isn't the same thing. I am asking if I can place limits on each SELECT statement but still guarantee that I will get 20 rows in my final result.

Comment: Yeah, so was that question. But the answer is wrong (even though it's accepted). I don't know the answer to this question though..

Comment: Ok well if you can remove the "This question may already have an answer here:" from the top of the post, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more limit 'outside' with the total count and use the same for the limit of the 2-nd query.

```
(
SELECT t.column1, t.column2
FROM table t 
WHERE t.status = 1 
LIMIT 10 # 1/2 of total rows
)
UNION
(
SELECT t.column1, t.column2 
FROM table t
WHERE t.status = 2 
LIMIT 20 # total rows
)
LIMIT 20 # total rows
```

Comment: That's nice approach but it will only work in case when 2nd query has >= 10 rows.

Comment: Well... you could add the 1-st query with `LIMIT 20` one more time.

Comment: I think this will solve my problem, the 2nd query will always have way more available rows than 20.