# sql two table select data with desc limit 5 ( or select data in two table last 5 entry)

Tags: sql

```html
<table id='simple_table' >
<tr>
    <th>customers ---</th>
    <th>visitors ---</th>
    <th>not show only for comment-----</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>john</td>
    <td>nevada</td>
    <td>table 1 position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>jack</td>
    <td>texas</td>
    <td>table 1 position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>table 1 position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>table 1 position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>table 1 position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>cherry</td>
    <td>right</td>
    <td>table 2 place</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>up</td>
    <td>table 2 place</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>table 2 place</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row9 col 1</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>table 2 place</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>..</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>table 2 place</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

hello is there anyone help me?
i have two table on same database i want select and list one query like that :

Table 1: visitors
select perid ,name, position
from Table1
order by perid desc
limit 5
Table 2: customers
select butid, name, place
Table 2
order by butid desc
limit 5

thanks advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Likely the solution will involve Window Functions to establish order for filtering to do your `limit 5` and that may be RDBMS dependent.

Comment: my database mysql and , i dont want output that  name, comment.

Comment: Asi what are is your expected table? what do you want the outcome to look like?

Comment: hi, totaly i want see 2 colum, for first table : name position (last 5 entry), second table name place (last 5 entry) ..
and out come is  comment (names) , data (position and place) .

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1  ORDER BY a desc LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT b FROM t2  ORDER BY b desc LIMIT 5);
```

I got this from the following post: [Combining UNION and LIMIT operations in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query)