# Random rows from MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table in MySql database with thousands of records. The structure is as below

[image]

Here the column "difficulty" has three possible values, which are A, B, and C.

Question is I need to retrieve 10 random rows from the entire table in which 4 rows are of one of difficulty type A, 4 rows are of difficulty type B and the remaining 2 rows of difficulty type C.

I want to achieve this with a single call. I am not good in writing SQL queries and looking for some guidance.

Thanks,

Comment: One option to make this task simpler: Write three separate queries for the rows with type A, B and C and use UNION ALL to put the results together

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE difficulty='A'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 4
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE difficulty='B'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 4
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE difficulty='C'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 2
);
```

Comment: This syntax is not valid in MySQL, you need to add brackets around the three queries. See [Combine LIMIT and UNION in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Here a fiddle with the valid syntax: https://dbfiddle.uk/ToH2LE91, you could edit your question and add this to improve your answer (since generally, your idea is correct)

Comment: Yes you are correct, but from what i understand from the question all i tried to do is set him on the right path

Comment: So what prevents you from [editing and improving your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40318/best-practices-when-editing-your-own-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand your problem, but I think this is what you want.

```
(
  SELECT * FROM your_table
  WHERE difficulty = 'A'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 4
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM your_table
  WHERE difficulty = 'B'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 4
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM your_table
  WHERE difficulty = 'C'
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 2
)
```

This consists of three separate `SELECT` statements connected by the `UNION`. Each SELECT statement retrieves the specified number of random rows for the corresponding difficulty type.

Comment: You should use UNION ALL here rather than UNION because UNION slows down the query and has no affect here. But then that's just a copy of [Aleti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76779414/18794826)

Comment: @JonasMetzler -Agreed UNION ALL is faster.