MySQL How to Dynamically Select Columns which have at least a value
In MySQL, I have a table which consists of 300+ columns, I have to extract only columns which does have a value at least in one row (not null).
Some answers from other similar question suggested that we can use stored procedure to select only column that is non-nullable. This is not what represent the needs.
The table is handling transactions, which I did not want to manually scan each column and rows, just want to figure out how dynamically we can achieve using SQL (MySQL).
Example using stored procedure but failed to execute:
CREATE PROCEDURE hrdc_ace_dl.find_aps()
begin
    SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct 
        CONCAT(
            'SELECT ', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS column_name FROM aps_transaction WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1'
        ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
INTO @sql
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = 'hrdc_ace_dl'
    AND table_name = 'aps_transaction';
   
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT column_name FROM (', @sql, ') AS tmp_table');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END


Please post some sample data and expected output. Include the details of failed execution if any, like error message etc.

Check this : https://dbfiddle.uk/CgcXuvzJ .. after inspection of your prepared statement, the error is pointing towards your usage of LIMIT function with UNION ALL. You can try wrapping each query in parentheses like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415380/10910692

CREATE PROCEDURE
extract_non_null_columns(IN table_schema_name VARCHAR(255), IN table_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = table_schema_name
          AND table_name = table_name
          AND is_nullable = 'NO';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    SET @sql = '';

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO col_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Concatenate the SQL statement for each non-null column
        SET @sql = CONCAT(
            @sql,
            'SELECT ''', col_name, ''' AS column_name, COUNT(`', col_name, '`) AS count_non_null FROM ', table_schema_name, '.', table_name, ' UNION ALL '
        );
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;

    -- Remove the last "UNION ALL"
    SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LENGTH(@sql) - 10);

    -- Wrap in a final select
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT column_name, count_non_null FROM (', @sql, ') AS non_null_columns');

    -- Prepare, execute, and clean up
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;

Explanation

Cursor Declaration: The cursor is declared to fetch column names that are non-nullable.
SQL Statement Construction: The loop constructs a dynamic SQL statement to count non-null values for each column.
Final SQL Statement: The last “UNION ALL” is removed, and the final SQL statement is wrapped in a SELECT to format the output.
Execution: The dynamic SQL is prepared, executed, and then deallocated.


Apart from the usage of LIMIT with UNION ALL functions issue, there's another part where you have to add to return the COLUMN_NAME as "column name". What I mean is this; below is the query with added parentheses to address the limit+union all issue:
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct 
        CONCAT(                              /* this part here */
  /*added opening parenthesis --->*/ '(SELECT ', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS column_name 
FROM aps_transaction WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1)'/*<--- added closing parenthesis*/
        ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') 
INTO @sql
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = 'hrdc_ace_dl'
    AND table_name = 'aps_transaction';

The current COLUMN_NAME in the concatenated SELECT will return the 1 which is equivalent of true. So, if you want to return the exact column name, simply wrap it in quotation mark like "', COLUMN_NAME, '".
Demo fiddle
